# Convert from Boolean to BooleanSupplier

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming, supplier

I have this function a:

```
public void a(BooleanSupplier param){}
```

that is called by function b:

```
public void b(Boolean param){
   a(param)
}
```

The problem is that function "a" is expecting a `BooleanSupplier` but function b is sending a Boolean. I think I should convert a Boolean into a `BooleanSupplier` but I could not manage to convert one to another.

Comment: `a(() -> param);` should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you @Turing85. Can you explain a bit this solution? :)

Comment: I down voted because 
[No research](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/)

Comment: It is a pretty straight-forward lambda-implementation of the `BooleanSupplier`-interface. A `BooleanSupplier` is a method without parameter, returning a `Boolean`. For details on the lambda syntax, I recommend reading a tutorial on the topic, e.g. [this one from `oracle.com`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html).

Comment: Thank you! I actually tried to read in the javadoc but since I have an Optional of a BooleanSupplier on function "a" this construction a(()->param) was not working and I thought it was the way I was calling it but now I could confirm that is actually the Optional the problem I think. Thank you again, Turing85, i will do the tutorial!

Comment: **Please read (again)**: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Comment: In your case Catarina, that means refraining from adding "Any help appreciated" from each new question. Please try to stick to technical writing - it is an expectation here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us take a closer look at the [`BooleanSupplier`-interface](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/BooleanSupplier.html). This is a functional interface, i.e. it has only one abstract method `boolean getAsBoolean()`. As we can see, the method has no parameters and returns a `boolean`.

Now let us look at the code presented. Method `b` receives one parameter `Boolean param`. method `a` receives one parameter of type `BooleanSupplier`. How can we convert the `Boolean` received by `b` to a `BooleanSupplier`? We just need to create a lambda that - when called - returns `param`. When written as lambda, this looks as follows:

```
only expression in the lambda -> return-value
        ^
        |
() -> param;
 |
 v
empty parameter list
```

The minor type mismatch between `Boolean` (type of `param`) and `boolean` (expected return-type of `BooleanSupplier`) is resolved through [autoboxing (`oracle.com`)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html).

So in total, we can now call `a` as follows:

```
a(() -> param);
```

For further information on lambdas and their syntax, I recommend reading a tutorial on the topic, e.g. [this one from `oracle.com`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html).

Comment: Great answer and tutorial, i am having a look on it! I just have one more question (maybe is answer on the tutorial, idk because I didn't finish it yet). If param is a Boolean and I can do a(()->param) why can't I do a(()->Boolean.FALSE)?

Comment: [Who says you can't (`ideone.com`)?](https://ideone.com/6eNwK2)

Comment: Oh, that's weird! I have "variable_one" that is an optional and I am trying to have a(variable_one.orElseGet(()->Boolean.FALSE).getAsBoolean()) and it do not work ^^' , maybe is another thing then. Thank you :)

Comment: Of course, there is no need to refer to `Boolean.FALSE`. You can simply use `()->false`. For the case of an already existing `Boolean` object, you can also use `a(param::booleanValue)`.